# Cannot connect cloud function to Cloud SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am trying to fetch data from GCP cloud MySQL database using a cloud function. The cloud function is written in Nodejs. This function is making a query to fetch data from the database. I have created a Serverless VPC connector that I have attached to function and MySQL. MYSQL has private IP enabled. However I get the below error:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at
> PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout
> (/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:409:13) at
> Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28) at Socket.emit
> (events.js:400:28) at Socket.emit (domain.js:537:15) at
> Socket._onTimeout (net.js:495:8) at listOnTimeout
> (internal/timers.js:557:17) at processTimers
> (internal/timers.js:500:7) Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at
> PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout
> (/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:409:13) at
> Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28) at Socket.emit
> (events.js:400:28) at Socket.emit (domain.js:537:15) at
> Socket._onTimeout (net.js:495:8) at listOnTimeout
> (internal/timers.js:557:17) at processTimers
> (internal/timers.js:500:7)

[image]

Below is my Cloud function code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const mysqlConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 1,
  host: '10.217.208.5',
  port: '3306',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'tmc',
  database: 'tmc'
};

let mysqlPool;
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
    mysqlPool.query(`SELECT * FROM tmc`, function (error, results) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(results)
    res.status(200).send(results); 
});

};
```

My Cloud SQL instance

[image]

Network for private connections:
[image]

GCP function VPC connector
[image]

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue. Do you have special rules in your VPC that discard that traffic?

Comment: Is the connector in the same vpc as the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: 1) As a test select `Route all traffic through the VPC connector`. 2) Since you are assigning a public IP address to the SQL instance, test using the normal Functions -> SQL method using an `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions That test might help debug the problem. 3) Remove the pool connection logic and try a direct connection.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a firewall issue. I allowed a particular IP and things worked. If u face a similar issue you may also try allowing 0.0.0.0/0 (Just for testing) inside SQL connections settings. 0.0.0.0/0 opens SQL to the world

Comment: Your solution opens Cloud SQL to the entire world. That is not recommended.